# cut audio file with iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio

Is it possible to cut audio file with iPhone SDK? (file has .caf extension)
I just need to cut off the silence at the beginning.

(Also, maybe it's possible to write new file from the existing one with specified start and end time.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this really so complex so nobody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Its not hard, its just fiddly, you can use [Extended Audio File Services](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ExtAudioFileWrite). have a look at the reference for ExtAudioFileRead & ExtAudioFileWrite (they have sample code) then you can open one audio file read it, trim it and then write the new one.

Comment: Hi Aran. Thanks for the answer! I see the ExtAudioFileRead & ExtAudioFileWrite but I can't see ExtAudioFileTrim or something.. :(

Comment: ok. I understand it. but the questions is - how to trim audio file? I can't just cutoff a peace of bytes, it will corrupt the file.

Comment: if it is straight pcm data (not compressed) then you can work out what to cut. on my profile there is some iphone core audio sample projects. one of them (the mixer) has a class called InMemoryAudioFile. it opens an audio file and puts its data in an array. PCM data is simply laid out. if it is a stereo file of 16 bit data, you will have 32 bit packets each representing one stereo sample. once you can get at this data its not much of a stretch to trim it.

Comment: @AranMulholland I don't see InMemoryAudioFile. Could you please provide exact URL please.

Comment: i think this is it https://sites.google.com/site/iphonecoreaudiodevelopment/audio-units-and-the-augraph/CrossFader.zip?attredirects=0&d=1

Answer (score 1):

There is no trim function. You have to write some code that opens a file for reading and creates and opens another file for writing. Then write a loop that reads the audio sample or packet data, discards the silence at the beginning, and writes the audio data to the output file.